# Layout does not fit the screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-appbarlayout

In my main activity have a toolbar and tabLayout that consist of 3 fragments with viewPager. The problem is that the layout of each fragment does not fit the screen when I do not hide my toolbar. But when I hide toolbar everyting works fine, all fragments fit the whole screen. I don't know what's wrong with my code

[image: Before hiding toolbar]

[image: After hiding toolbar]

As one can see, I can only see the label then hide toolbar which it should be. How to fix this to fit my layout with when I'm both hide and not hide toolbar.

My fragment xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapterViewPager = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    application = (MainApplication) getApplicationContext();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    this.setTitle("Hi: " + application.getEmail());
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: updated the code please check..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nestedScrollView` in your **activity layout** .. use this..

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to your nestedScrollView..

make your app_bar_bain.xml like this

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I have scrollView but it wotk fine, those 3 fragment have same problem.